# hive sql search a pattern for every letter in string

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have a string of length 10 and i wish to search specific character set for each character from position 1 - 10 . 
example in SAS  : if length(PAN_number)=10 and prxmatch ("/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][CPHFATBLJG][A-Z]\d\d\d\d[A-Z]/",PAN_number)

i wish to do a similar search in HAdoop / HIVE Sql

Answer (score 0):

you can pretty much do the same thing in hive sql. use rlike instead of prxmatch and query could be something like below(not tested). Three time [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] can be represented as [A-Z]{3} and \d\d\d\d can be represented as \d{4}

```
case when length(PAN_number)=10 and pan_number rlike '^[A-Z]{3}[CPHFATBLJG][A-Z]\d{4}[A-Z]'
```